# makeEwsRequestAsync not returning callback on MacOS Outlook2016

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

I'm using `makeEwsRequestAsync` to get email `"Body", "Subject", "MimeContent"`.

But in case of MacOS Outlook2016 when the email size is more than 1MB the callback method is never called after the call is made to `makeEwsRequestAsync()`. In case of email having size less than 1MB the callback is called with proper result.

I know in case of more than 1MB email size there will be an error with the message `Response exceeds 1 MB size limit. Please modify your EWS request`

Also, the same code is working on all browser, Windows Outlook application but only on Mac Outlook2016 the callback is never called.

Comment: Could you give us the Outlook version?

Comment: This was observed a year ago (April 2018), Don't remember the Outlook version. This issue resolved itself after some months, not sure if this issue is also back as `makeEwsRequestAsync` to get `<t:AdditionalProperties>... PropertyTag='0x007D'` isn't returning any response.