# EWS request not responding with error on Mac

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

In our Outlook add-in, we are using `makeEwsRequestAsync` to get the current email's `MimeContent`. We understand there is a 1MB request/response limit when using EWS via the JavaScript API. When we reach this limit on Windows, we at least see this message:

> "Response exceeds 1 MB size limit. Please modify your EWS request".

However, when making this request for a large email (>1MB) on Mac (Outlook 2016), we don't get any sort of response whatsoever. The add-in just seems to hang. Is there any way we can catch this error on Mac? We would like to show a dialog or something notifying the user that there was a size limit error, but we can never actually catch the error.

I found someone with a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935841/makeewsrequestasync-not-returning-callback-on-macos-outlook2016), but no one has answered.

Comment: Thanks for reporting it. Will check and work towards fixing it.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility apparently this issue was fixed but now since couple of days, `makeEwsRequestAsync` to get `MimeContent` ews calls are NOT returning any response even if the size is less than 1MB.

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal can you provide the build number? Is it an insider build?

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility Its not an insider build. Outlook version is `16.23 (190309.02)`, userAgent is `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)`. Also upon further debugging looks like `makeEwsRequestAsync` to get `<t:AdditionalProperties>`... `PropertyTag='0x007D'` isn't returning any response. I don't know if get `MimeContent` is working or not. This issue is wide spread to our add-in users and not just me.

Comment: This seems to be fixed on the 16.24 builds. Please update to the latest Insider builds, or the production build when it is out, and check if the bug is fixed.